# ArgumentOutOfRange Exception occured on leave Cell Fous

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When the user clicks on the cells, when it has a focus on it, if i want to open an another file, I'm getting an error message `Argument Out Of Range Exception Error`
I have added `try catch & data Error event handler`, still i'm getting this error. How can i fix this??

```
private void datagridview_CellValidating(object sender, CellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
try
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
        int newInteger;
        if (datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsModified)
            return;
        if (!int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(),
                          out newInteger) || newInteger < -50000 || newInteger > 50000)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            string errorMesssage = d_LanguageDropDownList.SelectedItem.ToString() == "French" ? "Entrez des valeurs décimales entre -50000 et 50000"
                          : "Enter decimal values between -50000 to 50000";
            datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = errorMesssage;
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception exception)
{
}

}
private void datagridview_DataError(object sender, GridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{

}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry i have uploaded the wrong picture, i have changed it. Please check it out.

Comment: At this line `datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";`i'm getting the error message.

Comment: Keep the `e.RowIndex` in a range of valid values. something like this `if(e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < 6)` //do this stuff (this is rough code)

Comment: Yes, it works. could you please tell me what is the reason behind this?

Comment: I think the `RowIndex` is always in the range when it comes from the event args. Is it possible that another thread removed some rows in the meantime, or maybe that you access a wrong grid view instance?

Comment: Good to know these things. What should i do with question???

Comment: I have already deleted one question which i posted by mistake. So, i don't want to delete it. May i update this question to ask for another question??

Comment: @HonzaBrestan, no, the `RowIndex` can be -1, too.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Oh, you're right, I completely forgot about this case, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for the event to be called when no row is in the grid, or on the "New Row", which doesn't yet have an index. So you need to check whether `RowIndex` is `>= 0` before indexing anything.

If you set a breakpoint you will see that before the error occurs, `RowIndex` is `-1`.

Comment: Yes, this what Mr_Green, explained to me. Thank you.

Comment: I think even if the RowIndex is `-1`, the exception shouldn't occur? (here exception is OutOfRange)

Comment: How can i handle, `Format exception`at this line `if (Double.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) <=
        Double.Parse(PrimaryRadGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString()))`

Comment: @Mr_Green: `SecondaryRadGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex]` would throw an exception if `e.RowIndex` is `-1`.

Comment: @linguini: Yes, use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, as `Parse` will throw a `FormatException` in case the value to be parsed can not be parsed as `double`.

Comment: Thorsten Dittmar: when i use tryparse, `cannot resolvce method`What should i do??

Comment: What .NET version are we talking about?

Comment: Well, maybe check your spelling - on `Double.TryParse` see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s27fasw(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19998/discussion-between-linguini-and-thorsten-dittmar)